# How should I initialize a new local account for a Windows service?

Tags: powershell, google-compute-engine, windows-service, windows-server-2019

I'm using Terraform with Google Cloud to create Windows Server Core 2019 hosts for use with Jenkins. I want to install some software like Git, OpenJDK, and others using [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/), and start the [Jenkins Agent JAR](https://www.jenkins.io/projects/remoting/) as a system service running under a local `jenkins` user.

I'm setting them up using PowerShell scripts provided via `metadata` keys like `sysprep-specialize-script-ps1` and `windows-startup-script-ps1`:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances

My problem is that I'm creating local users using Powershell like so:

```perl
New-LocalUser -Name $Username `
    -Description $Description `
    -Password $Password `
    -PasswordNeverExpires `
    -AccountNeverExpires
```

And I create a Jenkins Agent service using Windows Service Wrapper:
https://github.com/winsw/winsw

But when I try to run it without logging into the Jenkins user first I get back:

```
2020-08-26 14:49:57,760 INFO  - Starting the service with id 'JenkinsAgent'
2020-08-26 14:49:57,823 FATAL - WMI Operation failure: ServiceLogonFailure
WMI.WmiException: ServiceLogonFailure
   at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result)
   at WMI.WmiRoot.InstanceHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] arguments)
   at WinSW.Program.<Run>g__Start|2_2(<>c__DisplayClass2_0& )
   at WinSW.Program.Run(String[] argsArray, IWinSWConfiguration descriptor)
   at WinSW.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This issue does not happen if I first log into the `jenkins` user using RDP, which creates the user profile on first login. I assume that's what allows the service to start correctly.

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a user and their profile without having to manually log into that user so the service can start correctly. The setup and startup PS scripts are running as `SYSTEM` user, which might be the reason why using something like `Start-Process`, `Invoke-Command`, or `Start-Job` with `-Credential` flag to run a command as `jenkins` user to let its profile be created fails.

I've had issues trying to run a command or just `exit` as `jenkins` user like so:

```
[localhost] The background process reported an error with the following message: .
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2100,PSSessionStateBroken
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there some better way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

How can I create a local user **with** its profile so that the service I create starts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I programmatically cause a new Windows user's profile to be created?](https://serverfault.com/questions/946882/how-can-i-programmatically-cause-a-new-windows-users-profile-to-be-created)

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? Did the @Swisstone's link helped you in any way ?

Answer (score 1):

**Based on replies from a linked question** there are three ways (that look most promising):

1. Use [CreateProfile API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createprofile)
2. Use Powershell
   As [described in this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/946885/545593) - you will find [example on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/crshnbrn66/7e81bf20408c05ddb2b4fdf4498477d8#file-user-profile-psm1-L121) - in this case you will be able to define home directory path.
   Part of code which defines profile path:

```
    $methodName = 'UserEnvCP'
    $script:nativeMethods = @();

    Register-NativeMethod "userenv.dll" "int CreateProfile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserSid,`
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserName,`
      [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszProfilePath, uint cchProfilePath)";

    Add-NativeMethods -typeName $MethodName;

    $localUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("$UserName");
    $userSID = $localUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]);
    $sb = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder(260);
    $pathLen = $sb.Capacity;
 
    Write-Verbose "Creating user profile for $Username";
    try
    {
        [UserEnvCP]::CreateProfile($userSID.Value, $Username, $sb, $pathLen) | Out-Null;
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message;
        break;
    }
```

3. [Use `psexec` utility](https://serverfault.com/a/946888/545593)
   This looks like a straightforwad method but I'm not sure If it will Ansible.
   `psexec.exe -u foobar -p Abcd123! cmd.exe /c exit`
   Here's [more info about `psexec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have also tried using the [script you linked](https://gist.github.com/crshnbrn66/7e81bf20408c05ddb2b4fdf4498477d8#file-user-profile-psm1) and it worked fine with some adjustments, but ultimately I've given up that approach in favor of enabling OpenSSH using [this script](https://github.com/status-im/infra-tf-google-cloud/blob/master/setup.ps1) and then provisioning users [using Ansible](https://github.com/status-im/infra-role-bootstrap-windows/blob/master/tasks/users/user.yml).

Comment: Thanks for confirming :) If you think my answer helped you in any way I'd appreciate if you accepted it :)